# Convert stored procedure from Oracle to SQL Server with Oracle-To-SqlServer Migration Tool

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-migration, oracle12c

I converted below stored procedure with Oracle-To-SqlServer migration tool, but it's not able to convert it correctly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_Get_count(
ClientCountout OUT VARCHAR2
)
is

--Quarter VARCHAR2(20);
--ClientCount VARCHAR2(20);

--
--Quarterout VARCHAR2(20);
--ClientCountout VARCHAR2(20);

varQuarter VARCHAR2(20);
varStart_Date VARCHAR2(20);
varEnd_Date VARCHAR2(20);

CURSOR cr_client
   IS
    with dates as (
    select to_date('1-Jan-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language =american') startdate 
    ,      to_date('31-Mar-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language =american') enddate
    from   dual
    )
    Select to_char(to_date(Start_Date,'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'YYYY-Q') Quarter, Start_Date, End_Date from 
    (select to_char(add_months(startdate, level*3-3), 'DD-MON-YYYY') Start_Date,
           to_char(add_months(enddate, level*3-3), 'DD-MON-YYYY') End_Date
    from   dates
    connect by level <= 10) ; 

 BEGIN

            OPEN cr_client;

     IF cr_client%ISOPEN
       THEN
          LOOP        
            FETCH cr_client
                      INTO varQuarter, varStart_Date,varEnd_Date ;   
            EXIT WHEN cr_client%NOTFOUND;

       ClientCountout:= USER_BUILDER.get_Client_Count(varStart_Date ,varEnd_Date) ; 

       dbms_output.put_line('Client Count for: ' || varQuarter || ' is '|| ClientCountout);

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cr_client;
   END IF;
END;
```

Below is the converted stored procedure for SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USER_BUILDER.sp_Get_count
   @CLIENTCOUNTOUT varchar(max)  OUTPUT
AS 
   /*Generated by SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle version 7.8.0.*/
   BEGIN
      SET @CLIENTCOUNTOUT = NULL

      /*
      *   Quarter VARCHAR2(20);
      *   ClientCount VARCHAR2(20);
      *
      *   Quarterout VARCHAR2(20);
      *   ClientCountout VARCHAR2(20);
      */
      DECLARE
         @VARQUARTER varchar(20), 
         @VARSTART_DATE varchar(20), 
         @VAREND_DATE varchar(20)

      /* 
      *   SSMA error messages:
      *   O2SS0208: Subquery factoring clause conversion is not supported. 
      *   WITH dates
      *      (
      *         SELECT to_date('1-Jan-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language =american') startdate, to_date('31-Mar-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language =american') enddate
      *         FROM dual
      *      ), AS

      DECLARE
          CR_CLIENT CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
            WITH 
               h$cte AS 
               (
                  SELECT DATES.STARTDATE, DATES.ENDDATE, 1 AS LEVEL, CAST(row_number() OVER(
                     ORDER BY @@spid) AS varchar(max)) AS path
                  FROM DATES
                   UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATES.STARTDATE, DATES.ENDDATE, h$cte.LEVEL + 1 AS LEVEL, path + ',' + CAST(row_number() OVER(
                     ORDER BY @@spid) AS varchar(max)) AS path
                  FROM DATES, h$cte
                  WHERE LEVEL <= 10
               )

               SELECT ssma_oracle.to_char_date(ssma_oracle.to_date2(fci.START_DATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'YYYY-Q') AS QUARTER, fci.START_DATE, fci.END_DATE
               FROM 
                  (
                     SELECT TOP 9223372036854775807 ssma_oracle.to_char_date(dateadd(m, h$cte.LEVEL * 3 - 3, h$cte.STARTDATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS START_DATE, ssma_oracle.to_char_date(dateadd(m, h$cte.LEVEL * 3 - 3, h$cte.ENDDATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS END_DATE
                     FROM h$cte
                     ORDER BY h$cte.path
                  )  AS fci      */



      OPEN CR_CLIENT

      IF CURSOR_STATUS('local', N'CR_CLIENT') > -1
         BEGIN

            WHILE 1 = 1

               BEGIN

                  FETCH CR_CLIENT
                      INTO @VARQUARTER, @VARSTART_DATE, @VAREND_DATE

                  /*
                  *   SSMA warning messages:
                  *   O2SS0113: The value of @@FETCH_STATUS might be changed by previous FETCH operations on other cursors, if the cursors are used simultaneously.
                  */

                  IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
                     BREAK

                  /* 
                  *   SSMA error messages:
                  *   O2SS0556: Identifier USER_BUILDER.get_Client_Count cannot be converted because it was not resolved.
                  *   This may happen because referenced object is missing from the database.
                  *   It is recommended to fix and recompile all invalid objects in Oracle before attempting a conversion.
                  *

                  SET @CLIENTCOUNTOUT = USER_BUILDER.GET_CLIENT_COUNT                  */



                  PRINT 'Client Count for: ' + ISNULL(@VARQUARTER, '') + ' is ' + ISNULL(@CLIENTCOUNTOUT, '')

               END

            CLOSE CR_CLIENT

            DEALLOCATE CR_CLIENT

         END

   END
```

If you check SQL Server converted stored procedure, you will see "SSMA error messages" with details "O2SS0208: Subquery factoring clause conversion is not supported" and query has been commented by the migration tool.

Thanks

Comment: Describe what the stored procedure is supposed to do.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Actually I've have been given database with empty tables, stored proce. and my job right-now is to convert stored procedure and execute them correctly without bothering about data.

Comment: How do you plan on testing the execution without any data?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an Oracle instance to test and convert.  It's not really reasonable to ask you to create a correct conversion without the ability to run the queries on Oracle and examine the results.  In general this procedure is building a calendar, and then running another stored procedure for each row.

Here's a first pass at a SQL Server equivalent to that Oracle query, modulo off-by-one errors and minor formatting differences (which you need to test against an Oracle instance to validate).

```
with dates as 
(
    select cast('2012-01-01' as datetime) startdate, cast('2012-03-01' as datetime) enddate
),
levels as (
      select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) v(level)
)
Select concat(year(start_date),'-',1+(month(start_date)-1)/3) Quarter, format(Start_Date,'dd-MM-yyyy') Start_Date , format(End_Date,'dd-MM-yyyy') End_Date
from 
(select dateadd(month,level*3-3,startdate ) Start_Date,
        dateadd(month, level*3-3,enddate) End_Date
from   dates, levels ) d
order by start_date
```